# Error messages for form validation not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, input

I am currently building a window on a website where users can book a boat trip, which requires multiple steps, and 3/5 steps include forms (I only included the first form in the html since it would get too long otherwise - see below).

I am currently handling the validation of the first form, which you can see below **(".availability step1")**. I've spent quite some time on this validation, however, I can't seem to figure out how to make only the "empty", so the fields that are not valid, take on the error message **(.error)**. Right now it is recognising the ones that are invalid, and I'm getting the CSS connected to invalid (I am getting the **red border around the input field**), however, I am not getting through the html tag, which is a paragraph that goes underneath the input field.

```js
function init() {
    setUpBooking();
}

function setUpBooking(){
    formValidation();
}

function formValidation() {
    /* ------------ form & elements ----------- */
    const form1 = document.querySelector(".availability");
    window.form1 = form1;
    const elements = form1.elements;
    window.elements = elements;

    /* --------- delete default validation ------- */
    form1.setAttribute("novalidate", true);

    /* ------------ custom validation ------------ */
    document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // 1. select all inputs
    const formElements = form1.querySelectorAll("input, select");

    /* ------------ date ------------ */
    if (form1.checkValidity()) {
        console.log("form is valid");
        
        // loop through form elements and check if are valid or not
        formElements.forEach((el) => {
            if (el.checkValidity()) { 
                el.classList.add("valid");
            }

            // enable "next" btn when form is valid
            var counter = 1, step = "step";
            step = ".step" + counter;
            if (counter <= 5) {
                document.querySelector(step).classList.add("show");
            }
            counter++;
            if (counter > 5) {
                counter = 5;
            }
            step = ".step" + counter; // step is the class and we are appending counter with step so that it looks like the same class in the given class(like counter 1 means step1)

            document.querySelector(step).classList.remove("show");

            // enable "previous" btn when form is valid
            document.querySelector(".previous").addEventListener('click', function () {

                if (counter > 1) { // we don't want to remove the first step, it will always be shown
                    step = ".step" + counter;
            
                    document.querySelector(step).classList.add("show");
                }
                counter--;
                
                if (counter < 1) {
                    counter = 1;
                }
                step = ".step" + counter;
            
                document.querySelector(step).classList.remove("show");
            });
        });
    } else {
        formElements.forEach((el) => {
            
            if (!el.checkValidity()) {
                console.log("form is invalid");

                    el.classList.add("invalid");

                    document.querySelector(".error").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    el.classList.remove("invalid");
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

```css
.valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.error {
  text-transform: initial;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- AVAILABILITY -->
<form class="availability step1">
  <label for="date">Choose a date
    <input type="date" required>
      <p class="error date-err">Please pick a date for your tour</p>
  <label for="number">Choose passengers
    <input type="number" required>
      <p class="error passengers-err">Please pick a number of passengers</p>
  </label>

  <!-- PERSONAL DATA -->
  <form class="personalData step2">
  </form>

  <!-- ORDER OVERVIEW -->
  <div class="orderOverview step3">
  </div>

  <!-- PAYMENT -->
  <form class="payment step4">
  </form>

  <!-- buttons -->
  <button class="previous hide">Previous</button>
  <button class="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that calls `formValidation()`. Perhaps some code was left out?

Comment: How you want your validation? e.g: when your form is submitted, what will be your validation process?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just updated the JS snippet

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan When the form is submitted, it should move on to the next form, through the ".next" button and do the same in the second form and so on. I believe I'm mixing up the actual clicking of the button (that should only happen if the form is validated) and the validation of the form with error messages, that should be two separate functions, am I right?

Comment: Okay.... That just leads to the question of where is `setUpBooking()` called? What we're looking for is a [mre], so that when we click "Run code snippet", the code you're showing runs, and we can see it in action.

Comment: @meganelondono, so you want to fill all the fields of a form before going to the next section, don't you? Also if it's a date field then what you'll validate whether this field is filled or something else?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Yes, all fields need to be filled out. In the case of a date, it will already be validated since the default input value is the current date.

Comment: @meganelondono, has the solution worked for you?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan No it hasn't, and I must say I'm a bit lost. I changed the HTML to include the span tag in every form but still, no text is appearing

Comment: Can you share your html?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sorry. I've made some modifications to your forms.

Ideas are as follows:

1. Appended a `span` field in every form.
2. Before going to the next form just check every field is filled in the current form by passing the form number to the `validateForm` function and check all its input fields are filled.
3. If yes, return true else return false.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
function validateForm(step) {

    // console.log(document.forms[step - 1].elements);

    var i, l = document.forms[step - 1].elements.length;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        // console.log(document.forms[step - 1].elements[i].value);
        if (!document.forms[step - 1].elements[i].value) {
            // console.log("All fields should be filled");
            document.getElementById("error" + step).textContent = "Fill all the fields please";
            document.getElementById("error" + step).style.color = "red";
            return false;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("error" + step).textContent = "Form is completed";
    document.getElementById("error" + step).style.color = "green";
    return true;
}

var counter = 1,
    step = "step";

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener('click', function() {

    step = ".step" + counter;

    if (validateForm(counter)) {

        if (counter <= 5) {
            document.querySelector(step).classList.add("show");
        }

        counter++;

        if (counter > 5) {
            counter = 5;
        }

        step = ".step" + counter; // step is the class and we are appending counter with step so that it looks like the same class in the given class(like counter 1 means step1)
        //console.log(step);

        document.querySelector(step).classList.remove("show");

    }
});

document.querySelector(".previous").addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (counter > 1) { // we don't want to remove the first step, it will always be shown
        step = ".step" + counter;
        //console.log(step);

        document.querySelector(step).classList.add("show");
    }

    counter--;

    if (counter < 1) {
        counter = 1;
    }


    step = ".step" + counter;

    document.querySelector(step).classList.remove("show");

});
```

```css
.show {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- AVAILABILITY -->
<form name="availability" class="availability step1">
    <h1>Step1</h1>
    <label for="date">Choose a date</label>
    <input type="date" name="DATE" required>
    <label for="firstname">Enter a firstname</label>
    <input type="text" name="FIRSTNAME" required>
    <br/>
    <span id="error1"> </span>
</form>

<!-- PERSONAL DATA -->
<form class="personalData step2 show">
    <h1>Step2</h1>
    <label for="date">Choose a date</label>
    <input type="date" name="DATE" required>
    <label for="firstname">Enter a firstname</label>
    <input type="text" name="FIRSTNAME" required>
    <br/>
    <span id="error2"></span>
</form>

<!-- ORDER OVERVIEW -->
<div class="orderOverview step3 show">
    <h1>Step3</h1>
    <label for="date">Choose a date</label>
    <input type="date" name="DATE" required>
    <label for="firstname">Enter a firstname</label>
    <input type="text" name="FIRSTNAME" required>
    <br/>
    <span id="error3"></span>
</div>

<!-- PAYMENT -->
<form class="payment step4 show">
    <h1>Step4</h1>
    <label for="date">Choose a date</label>
    <input type="date" name="DATE" required>
    <label for="firstname">Enter a firstname</label>
    <input type="text" name="FIRSTNAME" required>
    <br/>
    <span id="error4"></span>
</form>

<!-- buttons -->
<button class="previous hide">Previous</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```